# Issue connecting Visual Studio 2015 to Azure DevOps after password change

Tags: visual-studio, azure-devops-server

For several months I've been using Visual Studio 2015 connected to Azure DevOps for Source Control through http://dev.azure.com/. My employer required me to change my Office 365 password last week, and now I can no longer connected to Azure DevOps through Visual Studio (I get error TFS 1003). But I can still connect to http://dev.azure.com/ from the browser using my Office 365 user and new password. Clearly my old password is cached somewhere, but I can't figure out how to clear the cache. I've rebooted mu workstation, but no luck so far. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

In the main Visual Studio window top right corner there is a drop down menu for managing your current user profile.  You should be able to remove and add your account(s) there.

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/signing-in-to-visual-studio?view=vs-2019#how-to-sign-in-to-visual-studio

> Unless you sign out, you're automatically signed in to Visual Studio
>   whenever you start it, and any changes to synchronized settings are
>   automatically applied. To sign out, choose the down arrow next to your
>   profile name in the upper-right corner of the Visual Studio
>   environment, choose the Account settings command, and then choose the
>   Sign out link. To sign in again, choose the Sign in command in the
>   upper-right corner of the Visual Studio environment.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks. Actually I was able to get Microsoft support involved and they were able to help me fix it. Here are the steps (in case anyone else runs into this issue):-

1.Sign-out from Visual Studio. 
     File->Account Settings->Sign out

2.Clear all the cache on the below location.

```
  C:\Users\%user profile% \AppData\Local\IdentityService 
  C:\Users\%user profile% \AppData\Local\Microsoft\VisualStudio\15.0_c1fd7470\ComponentModelCache 
  C:\Users\%user profile% \AppData\Local\Microsoft\Team Foundation\7.0\Cache>
```

3. Sign in to Visual Studio again.
4. Remove and re-add the account again:-

[image]